# Build no Gitlab não muda de "Pending"

Tags: github, gitlab

Recentemente eu apaguei um repositório no Gitlab (eu uso o próprio servidor deles) e criei um novo, mas quando dou *commits* e *pushs* aparece um "*build: pending*" no commit, alertando:

> .gitlab-ci.yml not found in this commit

Nenhum dos meus commits está passando (tendo sinal verde). Já tentei criar um novo arquivo *.gitlab-ci.yml*, mas não estou acertando. Estou iniciando no git agora.

Como posso corrigir isso?

Comment: Você precisa criar na raiz do projeto esse arquivo e inserir as regras de build nele, caso contrario não vai funcionar. E voce tambem tem que ter algum runner configurado para rodar esse build.

Answer (score 1):

Se o que você quer é utilizar o sistema de Integração Contínua (CI) do GitLab, será necessário ter um `.gitlab-ci.yml` válido em seu branch `master`; caso contrário, o erro mencionado acima vai ocorrer sempre.

Mas, se você não pretende usar o CI, vá até as configurações do projeto (Project settings) e desmarque a opção `Builds`.